# Random string generator makes string with wrong length (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function that generates a random string, but the string is sometimes the wrong length.

```
function getRandomName($maxChars)
{
    $nameChars = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
    $numOfChars = count($nameChars); // amount of characters in $nameChars
    $randomString = "";
    for($count=0;$count<$maxChars;$count++)
    {
        $randomInt = round(rand(0,$numOfChars));
        $selectedChar = $nameChars[$randomInt]; // random character in $nameChars
        $randomString .= $selectedChar; // adds to string
    }
    echo " ".strlen($randomString).", "; // length, string is echoed later
    return $randomString;
}
exit(getRandomName(6)); // 6 characters long

?>
```

Most of the time, the result will be something like `6, s2jd8q`. But sometimes, the result is something like `5, d82kw`. I only want strings that are 6 characters long, not 5.
Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `$randomInt = round(rand(0,$numOfChars));` to `$randomInt = round(rand(0,$numOfChars-1));`

If you run this

```
$nameChars = str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
$numOfChars = count($nameChars); // amount of characters in $nameChars
//$numOfChars = 62

echo($nameChars[61]); //Output: 0 (Last character)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same Problem! Somehow I managed to solve that Problem! Here is my ErrorLess Function to Generate the Random String.

```
public static function generateKey($length)
{
        $str = "";
        $chars = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^*(_=?+|%-";
        $charlen = strlen($chars);
        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++)
        {
            $str .= $chars[rand(0,$charlen-1)];
        }

        return $str;
}
```

This function is easy to Understand and works without any kind of Length Error! Let me know if it helps!
You can replace Character as Per your need for sure!

Comment: This method is very good compared with most the solutions here for two reasons. 1) It pre-calculates the length of `$chars`; and 2) you access the char by it's index instead of using `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while ago, it's something similar than the others but using substr() function instead. Here is:

```
function randomKey($length = 32) {
    $key = '';
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        // Get 1 random char from 0 to characters length
        $key .= substr($characters, rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1), 1);
    }

    return $key;
}

echo randomKey();
```

Hope you find this useful too. Regards.

Comment: Why use `substr`, just access the string index. ie: `$key .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) -1)];`

Answer (score 0):

I always use this my function to generate a custom random string...

```
<?php
  function random_alphanumeric($length) {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345689';
    $my_string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $pos = mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) -1);
      $my_string .= substr($chars, $pos, 1);
    }
    return $my_string;
  }
  $test = random_alphanumeric(50); // 50 characters
  echo $test;
?>
```

it print out: rqY4ePLhQYvu5d5m8Mfvcj8ZiYQbPu5tOzuIcMeWR5thmrlYpt

if you need two unique strings I suggest you to use this approach...

```
$string_1 = random_alphanumeric(50);
$string_2 = random_alphanumeric(50);
while ($string_1 == $string_2) {
  $string_1 = random_alphanumeric(50);
  $string_2 = random_alphanumeric(50);
  if ($string_1 != $string_2) {
     break;
  }
}
echo $string_1;
echo "<br>\n";
echo $string_2;
```

$string_1: `fX9KdYyFeF5JA5ceJpHTKy2uXaijwVvKsJlt288Xxg2q89BrNf`

$string_2: `g9RG4kdLgxxhu8QzmkWHH4eyH1WCaUjYaALejR26Nnzjvqmjw1`

Comment: If you're going to do it this way why not just access the char index? `$my_string .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that disposes with the array of chars, avoids `substr` and converting to an array. It is far faster then all the other solutions posted here.

```
function randomString($length)
{
  $out = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i)
    switch(mt_rand(0, 2))
    {
      case 0: $out .= char(mt_rand(48,  57)); break;
      case 1: $out .= char(mt_rand(65,  90)); break;
      case 2: $out .= char(mt_rand(97, 122)); break;
    }
  return $out;
}
```